# Is there a way to fool a PD device into using a non-PD Power supply?

Tags: power-supply, usb-pd

I have a collection of Raspberry Pi's all fitted into a nice custom case, I am using a large 5V 30A power supply to supply all the Pi's and it works great.

I have just received a Pi5 and it has trouble being powered up as the Pi5 is using PD to try an negotiate with the power supply for 5A but because the supply is non-PD the Pi5 restricts it self to about 1.6A and put up error messages etc.

You can by pass the error messages by pressing the Pi5 on-board power button during boot up OR putting `usb_max_current_enable=1` into the boot/config.txt, however this does not allow the USB to full power (as another message appears in the task bar just after bootup warning you of this).

So, is there away that will allow the Pi5 PD to negotiate with and allow the 5A to flow through from the non-PD 30A 5v supply?

Comment: The raspberry pi 5 is *not* using PD. PD does not permit 5 A at 5 V; it only permits more than 3 A when operating at 20 V. It's using some weird proprietary version of the protocol that only works with the power supply that comes with the rpi.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to create PD from a non-PD supply.  It isn't quite a trick in that the negotiation is real, but it does often require a supply with higher than 5V for best results.

Some cheap PD implementations use a SW2303, which usually has difficulty at higher power (the high voltage devices like laptops), and does a bit better with some heat sinks.

There are better implementations of PD but can cost orders of magnitude more, such as 'industrial' one on coolgear for $70 (SW2303 is under $20 even on amazon with shipping).

Given the prices, and potential issues going cheap, you may be better off just getting a PD supply if your power ultimately comes from a electric wall outlet 110-230 VAC.